# Parsing images out of a list using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

There's a html page like this

```
<li class="liclass">
some html
<a href="blabla" class="first aclass">
some other html
</li>
<li class="liclass">
some html
<a href="blabla" class="first aclass">
some other html
</li>
<li class="liclass">
some html
<a href="blabla" class="first aclass">
some other html
</li>
...
```

I want to get all the hrefs from the lis but like this that I can still get the relation between the li and the a tag.
So first li goes to first a tag, second to second and so on..

I have this code but it always returns the same a href context:

```
    foreach (var node in docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='liclass']"))
 {
    String href = node.SelectNodes("//a[@class='first aclass']")[0].Attributes["href"].Value
    }
```

How can I improve that code?

Comment: I guess the answer has to do something with the // before the a in `node.SelectNodes("//a[@class='first aclass']")[0].Attributes["href"].Value`

Comment: You're creating a new string every loop. That's why you always end up with the last occurrence of your search result.

Comment: and how to prevent that? normally I'd have 1 a for each li and I only want the href from the li that docu parsed currently

Comment: see @COLD-TOLD 's answer below. He declares the string prior to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to add all href

```
 string href="";
 foreach (var node in docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='liclass']"))
 {
    href+= node.SelectNodes("//a[@class='first aclass']")[0].Attributes["href"].Value+",";

  }
```